# C++ RTTI Registry Pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, rtti

I am interested in learning more about the advantages and limitations of RTTI in C++.  Suppose I have the following scenario:

```
class C {};
class C0 : public C {};
class C1 : public C {};
...

void print(int id, C* c) {
    if (id == 0) dynamic_cast<C0 *>(c)->print();
    else if (id == 1) dynamic_cast<C0 *>(c)->print();
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to implement the above example using a registry pattern?  For example, using something like this:

```
map<int, ?> registry;
void print(int id, C* c) {
    registry[id](c)->print();
}
```

Comment: You want two free-standing `print` functions with the same signature and return type, but called differently?

Comment: Your example shows polymorphism & virtual dispatch, it has nothing to do with RTTI.

Comment: You probably want to change the second `dynamic_cast` to `C1*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using polymorphism and virtual method seems more appropriate, you may use something like the following to register and dispatch according to a `id`

```
class PrintCaller
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    std::size_t register_class()
    {
        m.push_back([](C* c) {
            auto* p = dynamic_cast<T*>(c);
            if (p) {
                p->print();
            } else {
                throw std::runtime_error("Incorrect type");
            }
        });
        return m.size() - 1;
    }

    void print(std::size_t id, C* c) const {
        if (id < m.size()) {
            m[id](c);
        } else {
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid id");
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(C*)>> m;
};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/bM2jMk)

Answer (score 3):

This would most easily be solved by just making `print` a virtual function. Then you could simply have:

```
void print(C* c)
{
    c->print();
}
```

and it would do the right thing for all derived classes.

But if you want to keep `print` non-virtual, then as you recognize there's a question of how something like `registry[id](c)->print();` could work. The map's value type is a compile-time fact, but you want a run-time difference in behavior.

Well, I can think of one way to do that... by using virtual functions. You would need to create a class that works as a wrapper for `C` with derived versions that match up with the types derived from `C`. Some template usage could probably make this somewhat decent to deal with. Then the map is declared in terms of pointers to the base but populated via the derived wrappers.

But in the end the takes a lot more complexity and offers no more benefit than could have been achieved by just making `print` itself virtual in the first place.

Comment: The trouble I was having is that the `print()` member function needs to be templated (i.e., `template <typename T> print(T t)`) to implement an interface, so it can't be made virtual.  What would the derived version of the wrapper for `C` look like?

Comment: Well that rather changes the scenario since the template parameter is another compile-time factor. Where would your original `print(int id, C* c)` implementation have been getting different `T` types for its different if/else branches? I would wonder if maybe that templating itself could be refactored. But as your question stands right now, you might have actually trimmed away too much detail of your real situation to get an effective solution for it.